# Sample space of a random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

For reference this is from page 47 and 48 of Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger.

A random variable, $X$, is a function from a sample space, $S$, into the real numbers. So $X:S \rightarrow \Bbb R$. Let $\mathscr X$ be the range of $X$. We can define a new random variable, $Y=g(X)$.

This is where my question starts. My book says if we write $y=g(x)$ then the function $g(x)$ defines a mapping from the original sample space of $X$, $\scr X$, to a new sample space, $\scr Y$, which is the sample space of the random variable $Y$. That is, $g(x): \scr X \rightarrow \scr Y$

Why are they calling $\scr X$ the original sample space of $X$? Isnt $S$ the original sample space of $X$ and $\scr X$ is the range of $X$? Again why do they call $\scr Y$ the sample space of $Y$ when $\scr Y$ is the range of $Y$. Shouldn't $\scr X$ be the sample space of $Y$ since $Y$ takes values from $\scr X$ and maps them into $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Start by carefully checking the definition of RV and its dist'n.

Comment: @BruceET The distribution for $Y$ is $P(Y \le y) = P(g(X) \le y)=P(\{x \in \scr X $:$ \; g(x)\le y\})=P(\{s\in S: g \big( X(s) \big) \le y  \}) $. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure, I'd want to see the book. I think it may hang on the meaning of  "$\scr X$ is a new sample space."

Comment: @n.e. Your questions are legitimate and, from what you write, it seems that the authors make a mess of the subject. Unfortunately, textbooks in statistics (as opposed to, in probability theory) routinely do, even reputable ones, as do many curricula in the US (the situation in some other countries being less disquieting). Your post seems to indicate that you are able to stick to the definitions and to correct all this by yourself. Am I mistaken?